# NSURL for telephone always nil

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nsurl

This is my `NSURL`

```
let url = NSURL(string: "tel://\(phoneCall)")
```

It is always `nil`, although the `phoneCall` is a valid mobile number string, and I am testing on a real iPhone.

I tried

```
let url = NSURL(string: "tel:\(phoneCall)")
```

but it's still `nil`.

Comment: I did check and code run normally in Xcode7.1. let url = NSURL(string: "tel://\("0123456789")")

if let url = url {
    print(url)
}

Comment: `let url = NSURL(string: "tel://123456789")` is not `nil` for me on Xcode 7.1.

Comment: In order to easily debug use two statements: 1st create the string and then 2nd create the URL from the string. That way you can see exactly what the string is.

Comment: Omit the slashes - tel:number

Comment: Are there any space in your "phoneCall"?

Comment: What is the value and type of phoneCall.

Answer (score 0):

```
let phoneCall = "tel://9000002143";
let url:NSURL = NSURL(string:phoneCall);
    //OR
var url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "tel://9000002143")
if phoneCall == nil || phoneCall.isEmpty 
{
   print("phoneCall is empty or nil.")
}
else
{
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url);
}
```

Comment: In Swift `"tel://\(phoneCall)"` uses String interpolation. It will create the correct code using the "phoneCall" variable.

Answer (score 0):

Where this `phoneCall` is set?

I had a similar issue with a optional type. This code illustrate the problem:

```
let user = row.value
let phone = user?.phone
let url = NSURL(string: "tel://\(phone)")
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
```

In this case, the value of `urlString` variable is `"tel://Optional(\"11XXXXXXXXX\")"`, because the `user` variable can be nil.

You have to ensure that the `user` is not nil first, something like:

```
guard let user = row.value else {
    return
}
let phone = user.phone
let urlString = "tel://\(phone)"
let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
```